# Launching docker with parameters equivalent to compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm new to docker and trying to launch a container on my AlmaLinux 9, without digging deep into learning compose/docker...just experimenting with the basics.  The compose file for the container I'm using is [source here](https://www.zigbee2mqtt.io/guide/getting-started/#installation)  .

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  zigbee2mqtt:
    container_name: zigbee2mqtt
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: koenkk/zigbee2mqtt
    volumes:
      - ./zigbee2mqtt-data:/app/data
      - /run/udev:/run/udev:ro
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Berlin
    devices:
      - /dev/ttyUSB0:/dev/ttyUSB0
```

So U created a bash script (with minor changes) what I think is equivalent:

```
docker run -d --init \
   --restart=unless-stopped \
   -p 8090:8090 \
   -e TZ='America/Toronto' \
   -v /data/zigbee2mqtt/data:/app/data \
   --device /dev/ttyZigbee \
   --name zigbee2mqtt
   koenkk/zigbee2mqtt
```

On launching my script it asks me to pick a source repo for the keonkk/zigbeemqtt image, but of the 3 options only one works.  How do I specify the repo in the command line?  I tried unsuccessfully naming the image:
docker.io/koenkk/zigbee2mqtt

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the official image for koenkk/zigbee2mqtt has been removed from docker hub.

However, in the [github repository for the application](https://github.com/Koenkk/zigbee2mqtt/blob/master/docker/Dockerfile) you can find a Dockerfile. You can try copying that Dockerfile to the directory where the docker-compose.yml is and execute

```
docker build . -t koenkk/zigbee2mqtt
```

You could also add the line

```
build: .
```

to the docker-compose.yml (provided that Dockerfile is in the same directory than docker-compse.yml file)